# Test typescript union types with jasmine

Tags: typescript, jasmine

I have a unit test that checks the value of my route configuration:

```
expect(route).toEqual(['', 'login']);
```

`route` is defined as a union type of `string | string[]`

I have tried something like this, but doesn't work:

```
expect(route as string[]).toEqual(['', 'login']);
```

Jasmine reports:

```
Expected value to equal:
  ["", "login"]
Received:
  ""
Difference:
  Comparing two different types of values. Expected array but received string.
```

How can I tell jasmine to test my route as a string array?

Comment: Doesn't seem like a typescript issue, route is `""` and you are testing it to be equal  with the array `['', 'login']`, so jasmine reports an error as it should

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir Yes you are right! The unit test is working correctly; was my code that was broken!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As commented by @TitianCernicova-Dragomir, the test is properly written. Here a simplified test:

```
it('jasmine should interpret ts union types properly', () => {
  let foo: string | string[] = ['1', '2'];
  expect(foo).toEqual(['1', '2']);
});
```